# What happens to angels after qiyamah?

Tags: malaikah

So we all know this dunya is a test for only man and jinn. So that’s how Allah swt determines on the day of judgement who goes to jahannam or Jannah. My main question is what happens to angels since they never had a test and can’t be condemned to Hell. I know they will be resurrected but will they automatically go to paradise as it was their home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the name of Allah the most Gracious and the most Merciful.

Allah is the most Merciful , and he loves his creatures [Angels, jinn and human kind، and other that we do not know] and the default is bliss and Grateful and Complacent,
So the default place is heaven, only punishment for those who perverse and did the great bad things.

Angels by nature can not disobey, and can not do the wrong, and where ever they are in heaven or in any other place they are in the God's Mercy and actually that's the real heaven for them to be in the Mercy of the God ,

The only exception is for jinn and human as Allah give them the ability to choose and give them the ability to take decisions and Allah show them the right path , and actually this life is a major for us but it's temporary for angels (they were before man kind and before jinn and Allah only knows before what else !!!) and they will remains in after life.

To be honest we should worry about our selves and not to worry about angles in fact angels are worries about us and also praying for man kind as we are in the test not them.